# Methods to Estimate Optimal Distance Measure for Multidimensional Data Set

Tags: optimization, regression, distance-measure

My problem at hand pertains to choosing a distance measure for use in locally weighted regression. In my particular problem, I have a data set that is upwards of 10 dimensions, where the variables have different units (think distances, speeds, angles).

The way I am formulating the problem is along the following lines:

First, given some matrix $M$, we will compute a local Least Square solution, given some local set of data about $\textbf{x}$ defined as $\lbrace \left(\textbf{x}_i, y_i\right)\rbrace_{i=1}^N$, using the following:

$$ \beta^*(\textbf{x},M) = \text{arg}\min_{\beta} \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i=1}^N \text{d}(\textbf{x}_i,\textbf{x},M) \left(f(\textbf{x}_i,
\beta) - y_i\right)^2$$

Given that:

\begin{align}
\text{d}(\textbf{u},\textbf{v},M) &= \sqrt{(\textbf{u}-\textbf{v})^TM^TM(\textbf{u}-\textbf{v})}\\
f(\textbf{x},M) &= \sum_{j=1}^p\beta_j(\textbf{x},M)\phi_j(\textbf{x})
\end{align}

Then, we wish to find $M$ such that this solution is minimized at a set of separate training points, $\lbrace \left(\hat{\textbf{x}}_i,\hat{y}_i \right) \rbrace_{i=1}^P$, defined as:

\begin{align}
M^{*} &= \arg \min_{M} \frac{1}{2P} \sum_{i=1}^P \left(f(\hat{\textbf{x}}_i,
\beta^*(\hat{\textbf{x}}_i,M)) - \hat{y}_i\right)^2
\end{align}

where $\text{d}(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot)$ is the distance measure for the data set based on some weighting matrix $M$, $\mathbf{\beta}_j(\textbf{x},M)$ is the $j^{th}$ term in the local least square coefficient solution based on some weighting matrix $M$, and $\phi_j$ is the $j^{th}$ basis function used to represent the unknown function locally. The whole point of this is to construct a distance measure that can be used with a whole dataset $D$ and allow for an efficient and accurate non-parametric representation. Note as well that this distance measure would come into play using a KD-Tree for finding the local dataset used in the local Least Square solution.

Based on this formulation, the optimization problem for $M^*$ appears non-convex, so I would like to know if there's any other approaches that might be better? I haven't had much success thus far finding any information, though I might not know the right thing to search for.

I want to note that I actually have tried scaling each term of the vector, based on the variance in its possible values, and this did not really work robustly enough. I should also note for the angular measurements, I actually find the smallest signed angle difference in the $(\textbf{u}-\textbf{v})$ operation (ie $359^o-6^o=-7^o)$.

Comment: can you clarify how $d$ is being used?

Comment: @TolgaBirdal I have updated the formulation a bit so it should be more clear how this procedure should work and the issue I am trying to solve.

Comment: What are the actual units, what's "local" ? Or do you want to regress a small, representative subset of the data ? See LOESS, [Local regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking at can be reposed as the [LASSO problem.](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/sta305files/Rudyregularization.pdf) . Different ways of doing this. This is the problem you are looking at it a [weighted least squares problem](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/aai/2017/1736389/). It is actually convex. There are ways to do this with PCA.Which is the SVD of the covariance matrix.